# Removing suffixes or prefixes from a word and getting root word using Stemming or Lemmatization in C#

Tags: c#, porter-stemmer

We want the attempt to automatically remove suffixes (and in some cases prefixes) in order to find the **“root word”** or stem of a given word.
Pretty much always we find variations of the same words e.g. requirement, requirements, requires, required. All have **"require"** in common. 
So it should return "require" using **Stemmers' Algorithm**.

We have tried using **Stemmers.Net**, but its giving incorrect output like this:

- Exception - except
- Nothing - noth
- prevents - prevent
- clinical - clinic
- disclosing, - disclosing
- collecting, - collecting,

But it should display like this:

- Exception - except
- Nothing - nothing
- prevents - prevent
- clinical - clinic
- disclosing, - disclose
- collecting, - collect

Can somebody help us into this?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strStemPhrase = @"Exception Nothing in this subsection prevents the sponsor of a clinical trial from voluntarily disclosing, 
                                    collecting, or reporting information to the Food and Drug Administration ";

        string[] strStemmedWords = strStemPhrase.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        TestStemmer(new EnglishStemmer(), strStemmedWords);                 
    }

    private static void TestStemmer(IStemmer stemmer, params string[] words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stemmer: " + stemmer);
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word + " --> " + stemmer.Stem(word));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a Stack Overflow question.  This site is meant to help you solve code issues, but this is a bug/feature issue with the library you are using.  I would recommend opening a bug with the [official project site](https://stemmersnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @RobertPetz the OP is asking a question about a library, not reporting a bug. Although there *are* a lot of bug related questions. The problem here is the screenshot, not the content

Comment: @Ranjana don't post images of your code, post your *code*. Images can't be compiled. Don't force people to retype everything. Furthermore, make it clearer twhat the difference si. You typed two lists of words that look similar. What's the difference?

Comment: The two word lists look identical, apart from the whitespace. What is the problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos looks like it's the 'Noth' root that isn't coming through as expected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah. its my mistake.. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @RobertPetz its 'disclose' and 'collect' root that are not coming as expected.